# Top item of online shopping cart will not delete?

Tags: php, session

Building an online store using php and mysql, items in the cart session will all remove just fine with the exception of whatever the top item is. Any ideas?
Code for delete from cart:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
    $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
        if(isset($_GET['remove']) && !empty($_GET['remove'])){
        $delitem = $_GET['remove'];
        unset($cartitems[$delitem]);
        $itemids = implode(",", $cartitems);
        $_SESSION['cart'] = $itemids;
    }
header('location:cart.php');
?>
```

Add to cart:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['id']) & !empty($_GET['id'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){

        $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
        $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
            $items .= "," . $_GET['id'];
            $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;     

        }else{
            $items = $_GET['id'];
            $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
        }       
    }
?>
```

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: `&` a single ampersand is bitwise; you want `&&` and feel that this may be a typo question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  I corrected to "&&" instead of "&" but unfortunately still does not fix the issue, but I appreciate the correction.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store items as an array inside your session? Then loop through using `array_filter()` to reset the session with the updated array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to convert your `$_SESSION['cart']` to an array rather than joining multiple ID's in a string with separators.  You can then use `array_filter()` and `array_search()`.

```
public function addItemToCart($id) {
    # Filter through cart for the ID
    $cartProduct = array_filter($_SESSION['cart'], function($product) use($id) {
        $product = (object) $product;
        return (int) $product->id == (int) $id;
    });

    # If the ID exists, increase quantity
    if (!empty($cartProduct)) {
        $product = (object) $cartProduct[0];
        ++$_SESSION['cart'][array_search(
        (int) $product->id,
        $_SESSION['cart'])]['quantity'];
        return;
    }

    # If the ID does not exist, add new ID
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = ['id' => $id, 'quantity' => 1];
}

function removeItemFromCart($id) {
    # Update cart with the removed item
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array_filter($_SESSION['cart'], function($product) {
        $product = (object) $product;
        return (int) $product->id != (int) $id;
    });
}
```

Then to access your cart you can use:

```
function getItemsFromCart($callback) {
    if(!is_callable($callback)) return false; # Ensure it is a Closure
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) call_user_func($callback, (object) $product); # Pass every array as an object to the function
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
getItemsFromCart(function($product) {
    # $product will be used for every product inside the cart with ->id and ->quantity
    # Recommend making this a static call to get a connection rather than opening multiple - just demonstration purposes.

    $stmt = (new PDO('dsn', 'user', 'pass', [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
    ]))->Prepare('SELECT cost FROM myProductTable WHERE productId = ? LIMIT 1');

    $stmt->execute(array((int) $product->id));
    $cost = ((object) $stmt->fetch())->cost * (int) $product->quantity; # Here is your cost :)
});
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you. :-) I knew I probably wasn't using the best way to do this, and this makes much more sense.

Comment: You'll probably have to build on the `removeItemFromCart()` so you can decrease quantity rather than remove the whole product - but that is entirely up to you. If you have any questions, queries or concerns with how any of this works or you get stuck, just drop a comment and I'll get a SO chat for us to discuss it in.

Comment: Updated to show example SQL usage inside `getItemsFromCart()`